# Can I scroll to selected item in TreeView after search and found TreeItem? (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, search, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a TreeView with numerous TreeItems in it.  I have built a search function that works and selects the TreeItem specified but the TreeView scroll function does not scroll to it so one has to do it by hand which is not convenient at all.  Is there a way to scroll automatically to the node (TreeItem) in some way after the search has successfully finished?

Code for search function:

```
@FXML
private void searchButtonEvent(ActionEvent event) {
    TreeItem<String> rootItem = treeView.getRoot();
    String textFieldText;
    boolean flag = false;

    textFieldText = textField.getText();
    searchStatus.setText("");

    if (textFieldText.equals("")) {
        searchStatus.setText("Please enter something to be searched");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for (TreeItem<String> treeItem : rootItem.getChildren().get(i).getChildren()) {
                if (treeItem.getValue().contains(textFieldText)) {
                    treeView.getSelectionModel().select(treeItem);
                    searchStatus.setText("");
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    if (!flag) {
                        searchStatus.setText("Not found");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that might be a method just after

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().select(treeItem);
```

that might do the work.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use a counter, after selecting the item, simply call this instead...

treeView.scrollTo(treeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution finally:

```
@FXML
private void searchButtonEvent(ActionEvent event) {
    TreeItem<String> rootItem = treeView.getRoot();
    String textFieldText;
    boolean flag = false;
    int count = 0;

    textFieldText = textField.getText();
    searchStatus.setText("");

    if (textFieldText.equals("")) {
        searchStatus.setText("Please enter something to be searched");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (TreeItem<String> treeItem : rootItem.getChildren().get(i).getChildren()) {
                count++;
                if (treeItem.getValue().contains(textFieldText)) {
                    treeView.getSelectionModel().select(treeItem);
                    treeView.scrollTo(count);
                    searchStatus.setText("");
                    flag = true;
                } else {
                    if (!flag) {
                        searchStatus.setText("Not found");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method was in TreeView Class named scrollTo(int) so I just had to add a counter for that